# checkbox structure where If single child checkboxes are selected, then the parent checkbox should get selected automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myU10.png)I need to create checkbox structure with the following conditions:-

1. When a parent checkbox is selected, all child checkboxes should get selected    automatically.
2. If all child checkboxes are unselected, then the parent checkbox should get unchecked automatically.
3. If single child checkboxes are selected, then the parent checkbox should get selected automatically.

...this is how it should look like : -[this is how it should look like

this is my code. But it doesn't seems to satisfy 2nd condition. I think my logic is right but somewhere there is syntax problem. Please explain the changes you suggest or make. Thanks a ton in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>jquery3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="#"></script>
    <style>
        .col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block.px-0 {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-color: #eeeeee;
        }

        .col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .header {
            background: linear-gradient(#f1f1f1, #fff);
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
            color: #616161;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-left: 18%;
            font-family: Georgia;
            font-weight: bold;
            /* height: 9%; */
            padding-bottom: 2px;
        }

        .col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .Drop-down {
            padding-top: 4%;
            padding-left: 6%;
        }

        .col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .Drop-down .drop-down {
            background: #fff;
            border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 15px;
            /* padding-left: 18%; */
            font-family: Georgia;
        }

        .col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .selecter {
            padding-top: 4%;
            padding-left: 6%;
            color: #464f44;
            font-size: 15px;
            /* padding-left: 18%; */
            font-family: Georgia;
        }

        #submitbtn {
            margin-top: 4%;
            margin-left: 6%;
            margin-bottom: 4%;
            /* height: 23px; */
            width: 72px;
            background: linear-gradient(#fff, #f1f1f1);
            /* font-size: 13px; */
            font-family: Georgia;
        }

        .OU {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto my-3 d-block px-0">
            <div class="header">Manage Permission</div>
            <div class="Drop-down">
                <select name="dropdown" class="drop-down">
                    <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
                    <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
                    <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
                    <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="selecter">
                <div class="Property">
                    <div>
                        <input class = "parchek" type="checkbox" name="selection">
                        <label class="mb-0">Property</label>
                    </div>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Edit Property</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Remove Property</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Add Property</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="Testimonial">
                    <div>
                        <input class = "parchek"  type="checkbox" name="selection">
                        <label class="mb-0">Organic Updates</label>
                    </div>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Add</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Remove</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">View</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Edit</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="Users">
                    <div>
                        <input class = "parchek"  type="checkbox" name="selection">
                        <label class="mb-0">Users</label>
                    </div>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Edit User</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">View User List</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Add_User</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="Membership">
                    <div>
                        <input class = "parchek"  type="checkbox" name="selection">
                        <label class="mb-0">Membership</label>
                    </div>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Edit Membership</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Remove Membership</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
                            <label class="OU">Add Membership</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn">Submit</button>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!--$('.selectall').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('div input').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('div input').attr('checked', false);
    }
});--->


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.parchek').click(function() { 
$(this).parents().siblings("ul").find("input").prop('checked', this.checked);
});

//$("input").click(function() { 
//$(this).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').prop('checked', this.checked);
//});

$('.selecter').find('input').each(function(index, input) {
    $("input").on("change", function(){
      var checkbox = $(this);
      var is_checked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
      if(is_checked) {
        $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').prop('checked', this.checked);
      }else{
        var checkbox = $(this).parents("li").siblings("li").find("input");
         var is_checked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
         if(is_checked) {
        $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').prop('checked', this.checked);}
        else{
           $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').removeAttr('checked');  
        }
        }
    });
});
});

    </script>

 <!--else{
    //    var checkbox = $(this).parents("li").siblings("li").find("input");
    //     var is_checked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
    //     if(is_checked) {
     //   $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').prop('checked', this.checked);}else{
     //      $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').removeAttr('checked');  
  ///      }
 //     }}
//    });
 // });--->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: checkout indeterminate checkboxex - it does not fulfill your use case 100% as the parent changes from a check to a dash when a child is unchecked: https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/ - but in code, you can treat it as unchecked instead

Comment: Would you please update your question and remove all the code that's not specifically related to your question?

Comment: Hi Lotus, if an answer on this page solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to the group and to the child checkboxes for easier selection.
Your parent selector function is good, though I wrote it as below.  The child selector function should update based on if any boxes are ticked or not; you can use the `.length` property to get the number of checked child boxes.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xanderak/29y1ea7p/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //check/uncheck any siblings
  $('.selecter input.parchek').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div.checkgroup").find(".childchek").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });

  //check/uncheck parent
  $('.selecter input.childchek').click(function() {
    var numChecked = $(this).closest("div.checkgroup").find(".childchek:checked").length;
    $(this).closest("div.checkgroup").find(".parchek").prop("checked", (numChecked > 0));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had two errors:

1. This was not returning the correct value`var is_checked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');`, instead you could have used the already defined checkbox element `checkbox.is(':checked');`
2. Instead of using `.removeAttr()` in `$(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').removeAttr('checked');` you chould have used `.prop('checked', false);`

---

**Corrected code below:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parchek').click(function() {
    $(this).parents().siblings("ul").find("input").prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $('.selecter').find('input').each(function(index, input) {
    $(this).on("change", function() {
      var checkbox = $(this);
      var is_checked = checkbox.is(':checked');

      if (is_checked) {
        $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').prop('checked', this.checked);
      } else {
        let checkboxes = $(this).parents("ul").find("input");
        
        if (allCheckBoxesUnChecked(checkboxes)) {
          $(checkbox).parents("ul").siblings("div").find('.parchek').prop('checked', false);
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // helper function that checks if all checkboxes are unchecked
  function allCheckBoxesUnChecked(elems) {
    let allUnchecked = true;
    $.each(elems, function(ind, item) {
      if (item.checked) {
        allUnchecked = false;
        return;
      }
    });
    return allUnchecked;
  }
});
```

```css
.col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block.px-0 {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}

.col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .header {
  background: linear-gradient(#f1f1f1, #fff);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  color: #616161;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 18%;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* height: 9%; */
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .Drop-down {
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-left: 6%;
}

.col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .Drop-down .drop-down {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* padding-left: 18%; */
  font-family: Georgia;
}

.col-md-3.mx-auto.my-3.d-block .selecter {
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-left: 6%;
  color: #464f44;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* padding-left: 18%; */
  font-family: Georgia;
}

#submitbtn {
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  /* height: 23px; */
  width: 72px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #f1f1f1);
  /* font-size: 13px; */
  font-family: Georgia;
}

.OU {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>jquery3</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="#"></script>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto my-3 d-block px-0">
      <div class="header">Manage Permission</div>
      <div class="Drop-down">
        <select name="dropdown" class="drop-down">
          <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
          <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
          <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
          <option value="subsubfgh">subsubfgh</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="selecter">
        <div class="Property">
          <div>
            <input class="parchek" type="checkbox" name="selection">
            <label class="mb-0">Property</label>
          </div>
          <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Edit Property</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Remove Property</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Add Property</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="Testimonial">
          <div>
            <input class="parchek" type="checkbox" name="selection">
            <label class="mb-0">Organic Updates</label>
          </div>
          <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Add</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Remove</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">View</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Edit</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="Users">
          <div>
            <input class="parchek" type="checkbox" name="selection">
            <label class="mb-0">Users</label>
          </div>
          <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Edit User</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">View User List</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Add_User</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="Membership">
          <div>
            <input class="parchek" type="checkbox" name="selection">
            <label class="mb-0">Membership</label>
          </div>
          <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Edit Membership</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Remove Membership</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="selection">
              <label class="OU">Add Membership</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```